# What is this plant with an unpleasant smell and hairy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have received some seeds as a present, it should be some kind of flowers, but now (after four months) it looks like that:

[image]

It smells really not good and has thorny leafs and stalk.

Comment: Imperio, welcome! Please ask only one ID question per post - this makes them more useful for future readers (hint: 2 posts may be upvoted instead of one). You may always [edit] your post and move the second part into a new question. It’s always a good idea to familiarize yourself with a few details on how the site works: the [tour] and [help] are good starting points, also [ask]. We even have a special [helper](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) for identification questions. Again: welcome to Gardening SE!

Comment: Was there any kind of name on these seeds? And I'm not seeing any thorns in that picture - just somewhat bristly or hairy leaves - are they unpleasant to touch?

Comment: Independent of an id, those plants are not getting enough light. They are etiolated. Can you move them outside? (Just not all of a sudden, that could kill them.) You used the tag “houseplants”. Are you sure those are really houseplants?

Comment: @Stephie, thank you for your hint, I will divide it into two posts. And I'm not sure, that those are houseplants, but it's the only thing, that stand on the seeds pack, that they are houseplants.

Comment: @Bamboo, sorryfor my English, they are just really unpleasant to touch.

Comment: That's okay - this does not look like any sort of houseplant I'm afraid, much more like something that grows outdoors, but because its etiolated its hard to say what they are. Separate and grow them on in their pots in as bright a daylight as you can manage, see what it looks like later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks rather like Borage (*Borago officinalis*), which can have a sort of castor oil smell to it when rubbed. If not given enough light it will fail to produce flowers. As others have noted, it should be outside to get full benefit of sun and air. It's an annual, so in northern hemisphere probably a bit late in the season for any remedial action.