# What is this plant with curly leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have received some seeds as a present, it should be some kind of flowers, but now (after four months) it looks like that:

[image]

The seeds packing gave only the information that it should be a houseplant.

Comment: Since it looks like this plant has been growing in somewhat unusual conditions, low light perhaps, it might not have its normal shape and therefore present difficulties in identification. One suggestion would be to put the plant in some higher light/humidity conditions to see if it will start generating at least leaves of a normal shape and size, and who knows even a flower or two. That would help us a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Please also note the [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/42042/what-is-this-plant-with-an-unpleasant-smell-and-hairy-leaves) about a second plant in similar growing conditions and also from “mystery seeds”.